# Remember the value of selected field for a session

Tags: python, django, session, cookies, django-rest-framework

**Problem :** I'm developing a web application in Django. I have two HTML SELECT fields on the top of my header. I need to remember the values of these SELECT fields for an entire session. Moreover, if someone changes any of the SELECT field, I need to remember it too.

**Current Approach :** I'm using two variables in the URI and changing them if anyone changes the SELECT field (for eg: *http://127.0.0.1:8000/index?foo=1&bar=44*). In my views.py, I'm 'GET'tting these variables in EVERY SINGLE view function. Everything is working well and good but I feel this is quite an ugly approach as if someone manually changes the variable of the URI, an error is bound to occur.

Just like django-rest framework remembers the user who is logged in, is there any way to remember values in Django templates and views simultaneously? I've heard of cookies but I couldn't find a way to alter the cookie variables in the templates.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. In django there are built-in sessions. All you need to do is to call AJAX request using javascript every time someone changes one of the selects.

In view that is handling your AJAX request, just use `request.session` dict-like object to store changed values.

Comment: Yes except that in Django the session is just `request.session`, lower case.